# React: Make flash message disappear automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flash-message

I'm now implementing Rails like flash messaging to my React app. 
The flash message itself is fine but now I want the flash message to disappear automatically in some pages.
I at first used setTimeout in my Flash component but received this error.

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: enqueueCallback(...): You called  setProps, replaceProps, setState, replaceState, or  forceUpdate with a callback that isn't callable.

Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react/addons';

var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

class Flash extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: this.props.message
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let _this = this;
    this.setState({
      message: nextProps.message
    });
    if (nextProps.autoDisappear) {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        _this.setState({
          message: null
        }, 2000)
      })
    }
  }

  onClick(e) {
    this.setState({
      message: null
    });
  }

  render() {
    let transitionName = "flash-anim"
    if (this.state.message) {
      return (
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionAppear={true}　transitionName={transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={200} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
          <div className="flash-container" id="flash-component">
            <div className="alert">
              <a className="close alert-close" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>x</a>
              {this.state.message}
            </div>
          </div>
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      );
    } else {
      return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionAppear={true}　transitionName={transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={200} transitionLeaveTimeout={300} />;
    }
  }
}

export default Flash;
```

I consider other way to resolve this, but so far no idea. Do you have any idea to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to pass 2000 as second parameter to `this.setState` instead of `setTimeout`. It should be:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    message: null
  });
}, 2000);
```

And as you already used `arrow function` so no need to use _this. Just use `this`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, it worked. I should have checked twice. Also, thank you for the advice about 'this'.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass the integer `2000` as a callback to `this.setState`.

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    _this.setState({
        message: null
    }, 2000)
});
```

You most likely want to pass that to the timeout function instead.

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    _this.setState({message: null});
}, 2000);
```

Also by using the arrow notation you're effectively binding `this` to your component anyways, so you can skip saving a reference to `this`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it works now. Because Long answered earlier. I set his answer as correct one both of your answers worked though.

Comment: No worries! I don't do this for the rep. Glad it works!